# how to get Json objects from json array and use them with model class

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

I want to link my received json data to my pojo class using gson library.I used volley library to receive the data.What should i do so that whenever i call getter methods from my pojo class then i get the received json data.

My Json data is in this format.

```
{
 "vichList":[ {
            id=1,
            username="abc....},
            {....},
            ]
}
```

I want to get this json data into my pojo class.

Vich.java

```
public class GetfeedResponse {
private List<Vich> vichList;

public List<Vich> getVichList() {
    return vichList;
}

public void setVichList(List<Vich> vichList) {
    this.vichList = vichList;
}
}
```

Vich.java

```
public class Vich {
private int id;
private String username;
private String full_name;
private String createdAt;
private int vich_id;
private String vich_content;
private String city;
private int like_count;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getFull_name() {
    return full_name;
}

public void setFull_name(String full_name) {
    this.full_name = full_name;
}

public String getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public int getVich_id() {
    return vich_id;
}

public void setVich_id(int vich_id) {
    this.vich_id = vich_id;
}

public String getVich_content() {
    return vich_content;
}

public void setVich_content(String vich_content) {
    this.vich_content = vich_content;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public int getLike_count() {
    return like_count;
}

public void setLike_count(int like_count) {
    this.like_count = like_count;
}
}
```

Here i am getting the json response using volley library.

```
httpUtil.getrequest(url,this,new VolleyCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result){

            GetfeedResponse getfeedResponse = new GetfeedResponse();
           // for(Vich vich : getfeedResponse.getVichList()){
           // }

            Log.d("Response Result:",result);
        }
```

How can i get objects from json array and use them with the help of pojo class?

Comment: please use jackson 2 api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GSON:

```
GetfeedResponse parsed = new Gson().fromJson(response, GetfeedResponse.class);
```

Jackson:

```
GetfeedResponse parsed = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, GetfeedResponse.class);
```

Additionally, if you wanted to convert only list of Vich items (and you stripped your JSON accordingly) you could do following:

```
[ {
id=1,
username="abc....},
{....},
]
```

```java
List<Vich> viches = Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(vichItemsJson, Vich[].class));
```

Comment: How can i get vichItemsJson in List<Vich> viches = Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(vichItemsJson, Vich[].class));
?

Comment: Uhm, why would you want to do that? I just mentioned it as FYI that something like that is possible. You already have your POJO class - it's much better to work with that than manually converting every piece of response into needed objects manually. Simply do `GetfeedResponse parsed = new Gson().fromJson(response, GetfeedResponse.class);` as proposed and then you can get Vich list using `List<Vich> viches = parsed.getVichList();`

Answer (score 2):

Using Gson

Add the following dependency in your gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

In your `onSuccess()`

```
GetfeedResponse getfeedResponse=new Gson().fromJson(result, GetfeedResponse.class);
```

If you wish to use Volley and POJO its better to use custom GSON request. Check this link : [Custom GSON request With Volley](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2016/04/10/custom-gson-request-with-volley/)